# Existing non-bootstrap application, can I use modals?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an existing html/css design which unfort. wasn't designed using bootstrap.

Is it possible if I cherry pick and use bootstrap for dropdowns and modals?

What is the best way to approach this without conflicting with my existing html design?

I'm guessing the major issue might be CSS conflicts?

Comment: Oh god...I did this on a fairly large project recently - the way I went with was compiling bootstrap to only target elements with a specific class (we used "bootstrap" as the class) - all elements outside that class kept their pre-determined style - otherwise, yes, bootstrap will mess with a lot of your already defined styles.

Comment: I guess you could use the [customizing tool](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/). However, you could also make your own versions, but that might be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if you can cherry pick. [This site](http://www.cdnjs.com) provides a few links to scripts of bootstrap elements like modals and dropdowns but I think you still need the whole bootstrap file loaded.